# Vue: how can I make a grid instead of just rows in a table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Part of my Vue template looks like this:

```
<tr v-for="template in templates" :key="template.id" >
  <td width="400">
    <a @click="create(template.id)" class="hand-hover">
      <i :class="`fa fa-${template.icon} fa-fw`"></i>
      <strong>{{ template.label }}</strong>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How can I change it so that I have two columns instead of just one, so it fills out column 1 to 50% of the length of `templates` then starts a new column?

I thought about dividing `templates` by two then just having two loops... is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to be using a `<table>` per se, the easiest solution is to use a container with `display: flex` instead and `v-for` looped child `div`'s that wrap horizontally like so:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 800px;
}
```

However, if you really need to keep the `<table>`, you could compute a `templatePairs` array:

```
computed:
  templatePairs () {
    return this.templates.reduce((acc, n, i) => {
      i % 2 ? acc[acc.length - 1].push(n) : acc.push([n])
      return acc
    }, [])
  }
```

To be used like this:

```
<tr v-for="(templatePair, i) in templatePairs" :key="i">
  <td v-for="template in templatePair" :key="template.id" width="400">
    <a @click="create(template.id)" class="hand-hover">
      <i :class="`fa fa-${template.icon} fa-fw`"></i>
      <strong>{{ template.label }}</strong>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```